# What is the fastest way to convert string to array in python?

Tags: python, string, list

This is a line I read from a text file:

```
[54, 95, 45, -97, -51, 84, 0, 32, -55, 14, 50, 54, 68, -3, 57, 88, -1]
```

I used readline() to read it in as a string. Now what is the fastest way to convert it back to an array?

Thank you!

Comment: You have a `list`, not an `array`.  There are subtle differences...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the fastest, but it's definitely the safest/easiest:

```
import ast
lst = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

regular `eval` would work too:

```
lst = eval(s)
```

Some basic timings from my machine:

```
>>> s = '[54, 95, 45, -97, -51, 84, 0, 32, -55, 14, 50, 54, 68, -3, 57, 88, -1]' 
>>> def f1():
...    eval(s)
... 
>>> def f2():
...    ast.literal_eval(s)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f1()', 'from __main__ import f1')
31.415852785110474
>>> timeit.timeit('f2()', 'from __main__ import f2')
46.25958704948425
```

So, according to my computer, `eval` is about 50% faster than `ast.literal_eval`.  However, `eval` is terribly unsafe and should never be used on any string unless you trust it completely.  Unless this is a real demonstratable bottleneck and you trust the input 100%, I would consider the little bit of extra time worth it in exchange for being able to sleep soundly at night.

Comment: And by far the safest.  `eval(s)` may be the fastest.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart -- Yeah, seriously.  I'm not sure I've ever seen it go up that fast.

Comment: @mgilson That's what she said.

Comment: @TimPeters -- You're correct.  `timeit` shows that `eval` is about 50% faster on my machine.

Comment: This use of eval is disturbing.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix -- Care to elaborate?  I thought I made it pretty clear where I stand (don't use `eval` -- the speedup isn't worth it).  But, `OP` specifically asked for the "fastest" way.  I didn't feel like my answer was complete without it...  Of course, you could argue that DSM's answer is faster (and you'd be right).  It's pretty incredible -- but that wasn't posted when I posted this.  Also, `json` is a little more restrictive than python literal syntax, which is why I've chosen to leave this answer and not delete it.

Comment: @mgilson I'm just saying that uses of eval could end terribly wrong. The uses of `ast.literal_eval` makes more sense than `eval` itself (which was your original answer if I'm not mistaken). Also it's not surprising that json get parsed much more faster. The json parser is implemented in C and directly map to a specific data structure. While the ast code is simply compiling the code and filtering it. http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/ast.py

Answer (score 18):

Since we care about speed, in this particular case I might use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
>>> import ast, json
>>> s = "[54, 95, 45, -97, -51, 84, 0, 32, -55, 14, 50, 54, 68, -3, 57, 88, -1]"
>>> %timeit ast.literal_eval(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.6 µs per loop
>>> %timeit eval(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.7 µs per loop
>>> %timeit json.loads(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.61 µs per loop
>>> json.loads(s)
[54, 95, 45, -97, -51, 84, 0, 32, -55, 14, 50, 54, 68, -3, 57, 88, -1]
```

(Note that this works here because this line is sufficiently JSON-like.  It can't be used everywhere that `ast.literal_eval` can because not all Python literal syntax is valid JSON.)

Comment: Cool! I wouldn't have guessed that - impressive :-)

Comment: Sure DSM... I post a good answer and then you just have to go and trump it.  Kudos to you (and since Kudos aren't an official unit of StackOverflow currency, +1 along with it).

Comment: I prefer the solution with json as using eval could end terribly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If that's the string, go here http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

```
>>> s = "[54, 95, 45, -97, -51, 84, 0, 32, -55, 14, 50, 54, 68, -3, 57, 88, -1]"
>>> eval(s)
[54, 95, 45, -97, -51, 84, 0, 32, -55, 14, 50, 54, 68, -3, 57, 88, -1]
```

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ , I accept the suggestion, but I disagree on explaining `eval`. It's there, in the official python docs I posted, and IMHO it's more instructive to go there and read instead of repeating a piece of information here (and it's more "pythonic" too.)

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad link :p (it most definitely isn't), I'm just saying you should have at least once sentence of meta-text :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `python 3.6`

Here's my result of an actual string separated by `spaces`

```
stringValue = "123 456 789 012 345 678"
```

String to List

```
intValue = list(map(int, stringValue.split(' ')))
```

result

> time taken 7.586999345221557e-06
>
> [76, 96, 127, 255, 136, 164]
>
> time taken trying to print it 6.697199933114462e-05

String to List to numpy

```
intValue = np.array(list(map(int, stringValue.split(' '))))
```

result

> time taken 2.631999996083323e-05
>
> [ 76  96 127 255 136 164]
>
> time taken trying to print it 0.002241893000245909

String to numpy array

```
intValue = np.fromstring(stringValue,dtype=int,sep=' ')
```

> time taken 1.3830000170855783e-05
>
> [ 76  96 127 255 136 164]
>
> time taken trying to print it 0.0003395890007595881