# Replacing an element from list after checking for condition in python: doing it the "pythonic way"

Tags: python, list, loops, replace

I have a list of numbers such as:

```
a = [2,4,5,12]
```

I want to change the list by subtracting 10 from any element that is greater than 10.

I can do the following for that:

```
i = 0
for ax in a:
    if ax>10:
       ax = ax-10
       a[i] = ax
    i = i+1
```

But this is not a "pythonic" way of coding. I would be fine with this loop if I was using Fortran but Python is better than these structured loops.

Can I do this in another way?

Comment: "I would be fine with this loop if I was using Fortran". I don't know Fortran at all, but doesn't it let you write the equivalent of `a[i] = ax - 10` instead of doing it in two lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very pythonic way is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a [conditional expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
>>> a = [2,4,5,12]
>>> a = [x-10 if x > 10 else x for x in a]
>>> a
[2, 4, 5, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: Might also want to mention the term "conditional expression" for OP's googling benefit.

Comment: @mgilson - Good idea.  I'll add a link.

Comment: And now I come back and see your 4 upvotes and I feel sad because you beat me to it by about 30s :).  +1

Comment: @mgilson - lol.  Eh, that's just the way the dice role sometimes.  If it makes you feel any better, you did the exact same thing to me with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20363411/2555451).  I was just about to post the same thing when I saw yours.

Comment: I believe that right after I joined the 10K club, @DSM made some comment to me about how I now had the ability to see how frequently it happens to all of us.

Comment: Also consider whether or not you want to modify `a` in place, `a[:] = [x-10 if x > 10 else x for x in a]`, to get the same behaviour as the original code in the case where `a` is aliased.