# Exchange of variables between C and Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I've read a lot about it lately but can't get any further with a problem. It is about the exchange of variables from C scripts to Python 3.x.

To the C script:
I am working on the evaluation of IEC61850-9-2 Sampled Values (SV) and use the libiec61850 C library (https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850), which interprets the protocols. SV sends 80 samples per period (sine), which means that every 0.25 milliseconds a new sample arrives which needs to be processed. Therefore my script has to be fast.

Currently I use the following C script, which evaluates the protocols and prints the samples.
I hope it is understandable and my comments are sufficient:

```
#include "hal_thread.h"
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sv_subscriber.h"
#include <unistd.h>

static bool running = true;
int sample_rate = 80;
double sample[2]=  { 0.0 };

void sigint_handler(int signalId)
{
    running = 0;
}

/* Callback handler for received SV messages */
static void svUpdateListener (SVSubscriber subscriber, void* parameter, SVSubscriber_ASDU asdu)
{    
        double val1, val2, val3 = 0;
        /* read the INT32 Voltage Values on Byte Number 32 , 40 and 48*/
        val1 = (double)SVSubscriber_ASDU_getINT32(asdu, 32)/100;
        val2 = (double)SVSubscriber_ASDU_getINT32(asdu, 40)/100;
        val3 = (double)SVSubscriber_ASDU_getINT32(asdu, 48)/100;

        sample[0] = val1;
        sample[1] = val2;
        sample[2] = val2;

        printf("[%f , %f , %f ]\n", val1, val2, val3);
}

int main(){

    /* Creating a SV Receiver and setting Interface to Eth0 */
    SVReceiver receiver = SVReceiver_create();        
    SVReceiver_setInterfaceId(receiver, "eth0");

    /* Creating a SV Subscriber, which listens to SV Messages with APPID 4000h */
    SVSubscriber subscriber = SVSubscriber_create(NULL, 0x4000);

    /* Install a callback handler for the subscriber */
    SVSubscriber_setListener(subscriber, svUpdateListener, NULL);

    /* Connect the subscriber to the receiver */
    SVReceiver_addSubscriber(receiver, subscriber);

    /* Start listening to SV messages - starts a new receiver background thread */
    SVReceiver_start(receiver);

    /* Listens to Strg + C Keyboard Interruptions */
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    /* Endless loop until Keyboard Tnterruption */
    while (running){}

    /* Stop listening to SV messages */
    SVReceiver_stop(receiver);

    /* Cleanup and free resources */
    SVReceiver_destroy(receiver);

}
```

Now I want to pass the values to Python for further analysis and save them as Numpy Array. I solved this by starting the C script with subprocess.popen and reading the sdtout of the C script and converting it into a numpy array. Unfortunately this variant is too slow, especially since we might want to go up to 256 samples per period later.

Python:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', folder+c_script], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE) 

voltage_sample = numpy.empty([0,3])
voltage_data = numpy.empty((0,sample_rate * 10,4))

while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()     
        line = numpy.array(json.loads(output.strip().decode('ascii'))).reshape(1,3)
        voltage_sample = numpy.vstack((voltage_sample, line))
```

Hence my question: Is there a more efficient way to send the measurements to Python? I already read a bit about ctypes, but the callbackhandler svUpdateListener (which is triggered when a new sample arrives) is according to libiec61850 a void function without return. Therefore no value can be returned to Python, or?
Can Cython solve the problem?

Comment: One option would be to write a C executable using the Python API, which calls a function in your script with the data, but that might be too laborious for your purposes.

Comment: Your C program doesn't seem to do all that much. Maybe it would be more efficient to [interface to the libiec61850 directly from Python](https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850/blob/v1.3/pyiec61850/tutorial.md).

Comment: Sidenote: C is not a scripting language and (almost) always compiled to machine code. There are C programs or object files, no scripts. which are not C anymore once the source code is compiled.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tested the python binding, but it seems that the SV Subscriber API is not part of it. Can I do the wrapping by myself? Unfortunately I have no clue on how to do this.

Comment: @KevinSchäfer Sorry, I didn't realize that. It looks like the SV bindings where added to the .NET API recently (release 1.2 of April 2018), so perhaps the Python bindings will follow in due course. If you want to attempt it yourself, you'll have to learn about [SWiG](http://www.swig.org/).

Comment: In the meantime, perhaps you could pipe raw binary data from your C code to your Python code instead of wrapping it up as JSON text.

Comment: I agree that packing the data as JSON seems to be overdoing it, but I am still curious to know what performance you get from this. You state it is too slow, so how many samples can this code handle? At a CPU speed of 1 GHz you should still have some 250.000 instructions per sample.

Comment: About the JSON packing: I found that solution in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363395/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-array-in-python). Honestly I don't really know what json.loads do, but it seems to be much fast than ast.literal_eval(s).

Comment: And about the speed issue: 
To sample 1000 Sinus (= 20 seconds @ 50 Hz) I need 20,15s in Python, which is okay I guess. This is with a sample rate of 80 Samples per Sinus. But when I go up to 256 Samples per Period, I get a about 30 to 40 seconds instead of 20s, which is way to slow.
Btw I running the code on a raspberry pi 3.

Comment: isn't the pipe output always binary? Because in the Python console it prints the output with b' at the beginning. That why i have added `.decode('ascii')`.