# Alternative for ast to convert string list to list

Tags: python

I'm receiving data from Redis and I'm using ast to convert it to list. However for a bigger list, ast is taking longer time. Is there any other better way to do what i'm doing below

```
data = ["[[25565.75, 25565.75, 25498.3, 25535.8, '2018-01-01 09:15:00', 0], [25534.2, 25547, 25524.8, 25531.65, '2018-01-01 09:16:00', 0]]"]
t = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in data] 
print(t)
```

Comment: you could use ast still but inside a generator instead perhaps. Use the values as-needed. EDIT: is data always a list of a single element though? It seems to be in this example.

Comment: You could try `json.loads` but might well be you need to re-think your storage options if you're storing lists of lists that need serializing each way...

Comment: yes, data is always a list of a single element

Comment: It might help you to read [What is the fastest way to convert string to array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20363395/10657880)