# How to Array value access from python file

Tags: python-3.x, file, arraylist

I have array into my file 'test.txt' such like

```
[[100, 'Prosenjit Das', 'researcher', 'D1', '03:12:12', '10:10:48', 'P_Status'], [20, 'Arif Khan', 'Managing Director', 'D1', '09:14:41', '11:03:06', 'P_Status'], [13, 'Mr. hasib', 'Managing Director', 'D1', '00:14:49', '00:00:00', 'P_Status'], [1, 'Antu Sarkar', 'Engineer', 'D1', '00:11:54', '08:55:07', 'P_Status'], [25, 'Avijit', 'Managing Director', 'D1', '00:08:10', '00:00:00', 'P_Status']]
```

## I've tried this code

```
with open('test.txt') as fp:
    pagla = fp.readline()

for data in pagla:
    print(data[4])
```

I wanted to access here 4th number index value.

But throwing the following error
"IndexError: string index out of range"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQRLY.png)

Comment: Are you referring to the 4th element in each list of list or the 4th element in a particular list?

Comment: yes @Edeki Okoh

Comment: I asked two questions. Which one are you saying yes to?

Comment: Simply we can access value by index, but here every single character is string that's why i can't access by index

Comment: First what is before_the_end_line even equal to? I do not see it initialized anywhere. I wrote a test script and it works.

Comment: 4 is not a list that's a index and both answer is yes

Comment: sorry @Edeki Okoh. i mistook. edited again, please see that.

Comment: just above array in my "pagla" value. I think you understand

Comment: Then please give me answer

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a list of list there are many ways to index it. First you can loop over the list within the list and print out a specific element inside of that list. For example:

```
list_s = [[100, 'Prosenjit Das', 'researcher', 'D1', '03:12:12', '10:10:48', 'P_Status'], [20, 'Arif Khan', 'Managing Director', 'D1', '09:14:41', '11:03:06', 'P_Status'], [13, 'Mr. hasib', 'Managing Director', 'D1', '00:14:49', '00:00:00', 'P_Status'], [1, 'Antu Sarkar', 'Engineer', 'D1', '00:11:54', '08:55:07', 'P_Status'], [25, 'Avijit', 'Managing Director', 'D1', '00:08:10', '00:00:00', 'P_Status']]

for list in list_s:
    print(list[3])
```

Output:

```
D1
D1
D1
D1
D1
```

Which is the 4th element in each of the list contained in the list. Or you can do the following known as double indexing:

```
print(list_s[0][4])
```

Output:

```
03:12:12
```

Which prints out the 5th element in the first list contained in the list of list. This is better used if you want a specific element contained in a sublist.

Comment: it's not working. I've tried it simply before. This array comes from test.txt file and that's why there everything string. i can't specific value with simple index like a normal array.

Comment: but I've told there this "I've a array into my file". Obviously first i'm read that file 'test.txt' so it's not normal array list.

Comment: I've tried several times and it doesn't work, that's why i asked this question.  But Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363395/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-array-in-python